# Windows 8 ListView - how to stop ListView animating on click

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have a ListView object currently defined in xaml like this:

```
<ListView 
            x:Name="itemListView" 
            Margin="0" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalContentAlignment="Top" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FixtureItem}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource fixtureGroups}}"
            SelectionMode="None" IsSwipeEnabled="True"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
            ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False" ManipulationMode="None">
```

When I tap an item in the list view it does a little bounce animation. How can I stop it doing this?

Comment: Is this a Windows store app, WPF, or Silverlight? Please add the appropriate tag to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using xaml, you'll just have to take that animation out of the Pressed State in the VisualStateManager of that controls [Item Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709915.aspx).

You're looking to turn this;

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
  <Storyboard>
    <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer" />
  </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

into just this;

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
```

Hope this helps, Cheers.

Comment: Any links you can point me to that show how to change the visual state of a buttons pressed state? I'm struggling to find good examples.

Comment: They're all more or less the same. You're just editing that particular state in the `VisualStateManager` of the controls template. An easy way to do expose that is right-click the button control, choose edit template, find the "Pressed" state in the VSM and edit the same way as shown above. Expression Blend is especially handy for dealing with templates. I'd be willing to bet a quick trip to a search engine or youtube would give you an easy how-to.